# Do I need Dajaxice fully configured to use Dajax in Django?

Tags: django, dajaxice

This may be a silly question, but do I need Dajaxice fully configured to run Dajax?

I want to use Dajax because I would need some heavy jQuery DOM manipulation. The [Dajax installation documentation](https://github.com/jorgebastida/django-dajax/wiki/installation) says that Dajaxice needs to be installed to run Dajax.

But do I need to specify `{% load dajaxice_templatetags %}` and `{% dajaxice_js_import %}` (inside `<head>`) if I am only using Dajax?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you do. But why not to try before asking?

Comment: Thanks and I did try :-), I actually included the `dajaxice` template stuff at first and took them off and in both cases it threw an error. Later I found out I had to serve `jQuery` on my own. I thought `jquery.dajax.core.js` came with its own version of `jQuery`.